# Setting specific image to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uiimageview

I have 10 images named 0.png to 9.png and also a randomiser give me a random number between these 10.

And well depending on the number the randomiser gives me, I want to set my `UIImageView` with that image.

My idea was to do it like this:

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"%d.jpg", currentQuestion]];
```

As this works fine when I'm setting the text of a `NSLog` with the random number like this:

```
NSLog(@"Some Text %d", currentQuestion);
```

However when I try to set the image I get this error:

> Too many arguments to method call, excepted 1, have 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code instead:

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", currentQuestion]]];
```

The thing that `+imageNamed:` takes only one argument and you should construct it as formatted string, whereas `NSLog` can take variable number of arguments

Also you say that you have `0.png` to `9.png` but construct image names using `jpg`. Please check the extension too

Answer (score 2):

First, as @Azat said, you should use one specific `NSString` as the parameter of `imageNamed:` method.

In addition, a better way to achieve this may use a `NSArray` to store the names of these candidate images like:

```
NSArray *imageNames = @[@"1.png", @"2.png", @"3.png"];
```

Then, you could use the random number as the index of the image name array instead of constructing the image name by yourself.

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNames[currentQuestion]]]
```

A benefit to do this way is you don't need to modify your code even if the name of imaged were changed, just change the name in the image names array.